# Does Raspbian start its automatic services/daemons when it's turned or when someone logs in?

Tags: boot, login, putty, services

I'm using Raspbian. I connect through Putty. My question is, before I connect with Putty, is the Pi actually doing anything or is it just sitting their idly? Before logged in, does it start the services that are supposed to start at startup?

Also, can I login to the same account on Raspbian from two different computers?

I ask because I have Deluge setup as a service on startup. I had turned on the Raspberry Pi, and assuming the web interface reported correctly, it seemed that it was not doing anything until I actually logged into the Pi through Putty.

Comment: yes, system services are run on boot - and you can login as many times as you like from as many computers as you like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you turn on your pi the daemons and automatic services start.
If you want something to run each time someone logs in you would put that command in the .profile file in ur home directory. there is a different file for commands tht should run each time you turn it on. you can also use chrontab to time commands that should run only at certain times or events. similar to .profile is ur .bashrc in ur home directory. you can move the command to /etc/rc.local to run when raspberry pi starts

for example my appache (since you ask about webinterface) and pihole starts each time i turn it on but does not run an additional time when i log in as it would with commands in .profile.

and yes you can login with the same account or many accounts into the pi multiple times at the same time.

just try not to write a command that does not make sense, as that might make you lock out and have to manually remove microSD to edit the file from a separate computer which would be rather annoying.

Comment: Please do not advice to use deprecated `/etc/rc.local`. Note that using it has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.